# How to extract a node in a Postgres record datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

I am using Postgres 9.1 and I have a function that returns a `record` datatype using the `row()` function.

For a simple example, try:

```
select row(1,2,3);
```

It will return a single-cell row with "(1,2,3)" in it.

In my more complex function, it returns a geocode and other data as in:

`(90,"Sydney, Australia",0.431951065304161,151.208784,-33.873982)`

So what I am trying to do is figure out how to exact each of these node values in this "row" or "array" (whatever is technically correct).

Anybody that can help, this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example function:

```
create or replace function a_function()
returns record language sql as $$
    select 90, 'Sydney, Australia'::text, 0.431951065304161, 151.208784, -33.873982;
$$;

select a_function();

                            a_function                            
------------------------------------------------------------------
 (90,"Sydney, Australia",0.431951065304161,151.208784,-33.873982)
(1 row)
```

You should call the function in from clause with a column definition list:

```
select *
from a_function() as (id int, city text, num1 numeric, num2 numeric, num3 numeric);

 id |       city        |       num1        |    num2    |    num3    
----+-------------------+-------------------+------------+------------
 90 | Sydney, Australia | 0.431951065304161 | 151.208784 | -33.873982
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept searching and I found the answer this doc:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_data_types.htm

Look under "Accessing Composite Types".

Essentially the `record` array is an associative array (or key=>value pair).

You have to use the key name in order to pull it out of the array.